# Fast arbitrary insert of new rows into a pandas dataframe when the new row index is already in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a large pandas dataframe that when certain conditions are met I want to insert new rows at the same index of where that condition is met in a fast way.

The code I have now is

```
rowsToDuplicateAndAdjust = data[booleanConditionArray] # get rows where I want to insert new rows
for index, row in rowsToDuplicateAndAdjust:
        rowA, rowB = generateNewRows(row) # generate new rows
        data = pd.concat([data[data.index <= index], rowB.to_frame().T, rowB.to_frame().T, data[data.index > index]], axis=0) # insert rows I want at the correct place, this is the slow part
```

This works but is very slow as I end up calling concat many times (could be on the order of 10k times). How should I do this better? I would like to do something like data.loc[index] = rowA etc but as that index already exists loc ends up overwriting it which is not what I want

Comment: I found a large speed up by generating all the rows then appending them all at the end of the dataframe and then sorting by the index.